# Zenjava, javafx maven and packaging with the dependancies

Tags: java, maven, build

Ok so I have a maven project which uses javafx. At the moment packaging produces a jar file along with a folder called lib with my external dependencies in there. is there any way i can get it so that it includes these dependencies. I know that on the old zenjava archive (https://web.archive.org/web/20141004205604/http://zenjava.com:80/javafx/maven/jar-bundle.html) it says that older versions did?

Here's my build part of my pom

```
<build>
    <finalName>ClientSideMaven</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.canon.cel.consoleserverclient.MainApp</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-jfxjar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer, dont! The maven assembly plugin allows you to do so

```
             <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-executable</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${test.pack.dir}</outputDirectory>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.canon.cel.consoleserverclient.MainApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```